# Chord progression question

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions, modal

Dmaj7 - Emaj7 - Gbmaj7 - Gbmaj7 x repeats
What is this chord progression?
I could not figure out its key and know nothing about this one.

It is from this video.

Answer (score 5):

Call that F♯maj7 rather than G♭maj7 and it starts to make more sense!

I'm hearing F♯ as the tonal centre.   It's not a functional progression.   Just F♯maj7 approached by a couple of similar-shaped chords  two and one whole step below.   This is called 'planing'. There's a discussion of the technique here:
https://www.secretsofsongwriting.com/2008/09/04/chord-progressions-can-come-alive-with-planing/

As mentioned in a comment, 'planing' became popular with the French impressionist composers, particularly Ravel and Debussy.   It's the antithesis of Common Practice harmony, where parallel 5ths and octaves were avoided.   EVERYTHING's parallel in planing!

Jazz theory tends to obsess on functional harmony, always looking for 'progressions'.  We must remember that one perfectly valid way that a chord can 'fit' is simply being the same shape as the one before it.

Comment: Also, what scales or chord tones did he use on this chord progression? Or any other scales or mode that would fit well on it.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the term "planing". I remember being introduced to Ravel's "Pavane pour une infante défunte" which has an example of planing which really stands out.

Comment: Yes, the French impressionist composers were big on planing!

Comment: Guitars are so good for planing, you might want one in your woodworking tool kit.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to 'plane' on guitar. Which is probably how many guitarists first discover it sounds good!   Keyboard players tend instead to discover 'diatonic planing' - Cmaj7, Dm7, Em7, Fmaj7 etc. -  which lies much more easily under their fingers.   True planing is a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different way to look at this. It's D - E - F#, with F# being the tonal center, and the relevant trick that makes this interesting is alternating between F# major and F# minor sounds. While the D and E chords are playing, it sounds like things from F# minor i.e. A major would fit (with come added twist like the D# in Emaj7), but then every time there's a "surprising" change - instead of F#m you get F#. "Surprising" in quotes, because it's not really surprising at all, switching between parallel major and minor is a very common thing to do in jazzy genres.

Try playing F# minor pentatonic or F# blues licks over it, they should fit just about everywhere, including the F# major chord. Toy around with solo A and A# notes, when the F# major chord is sounding.

"Planing" might describe what happens with the guitar chords, because the chord progression can be played by keeping the same fingering pattern but moving the left hand to a different position. But a practically identical chord progression would be:

Emaj7 - C#m9 - F#maj7

or

Bm9 - C#m9 - F#maj7

or, actually you can even change the F#maj7 and make it, say, D#m9. So

Bm9 - C#m9 - D#m9

or if you like, split the second bar in half:

Emaj7 - C#m9 - F#maj7 - D#m9

And as you can see, these don't have to be played with "planing". Actually, you can EQ out the bass in the video and change the video to one of these other versions by playing the bass notes from above over the video. And all the solos on the video would sound practically the same. The idea is the same during the first two chords, you treat it like being in F# minor, and during the last chords you treat it like being in F# major.

Here's my favourite variation written out with the implied scale changes explicated as key signatures: (I tested that this works perfectly over the video, too bad we can't have audio clips here)

[image: chord progression variation notated]

Note that during Emaj7 or C#m9 chords, despite the key signature markings, D is sharpened. That's just one more trick that brings extra flavor. Even over the second bar with six sharps, you *can* play anything you want there, including E even though there's an E# in the default scale and in the F#maj7 chord. Or A even though there's an A# in the default scale and in the F#maj7 chord. Try all notes over all chords and learn what the combinations taste like. :)

Planing can be a creative technique for coming up with progressions like that. But when you start doing variations of the chord progression to find out what is its harmonic essence, you may find that no planing is needed to play what's essential to the progression. This is probably somewhat subjective, but in my opinion, it doesn't change the "song" at all whether you have E or C# in the bass. Or D vs B. If you're bored with one, use the other one.

Comment: 'Planing' is easy on guitar, not so much on keyboard!   But that's not the point.   It's primarily a musical device that lets you play step-adjacent chords of the same shape without having to worry about them all fitting the same scale or the same key.  The unity comes simply from them being the same shape, and adjacent.

Comment: @LaurencePayne It seems I have to repeat everything I said in the answer. Planing is a technique that can be used to come up with the OP's progression. But planing is not needed for reproducing the essential harmonic elements in that progression. It doesn't need to be planed. The essential thing is not that the chord shapes are exactly the same. They are not, other instruments are playing and the total sound is not only the guitar's planed chords. You could even leave out the whole guitar and play something different and it would be identical. The soloists do not think about planing.

Comment: @LaurencePayne  Planing is not needed for reproducing the end-result. Not as a technique, or in the voicings. The voicings do not have to be planed. The alternative variations I listed work pretty much exactly the same or better. If the progression had been the one I wrote in the notation example, and the OP had asked what's happening here, would you have answered, "planing". What does the soloist think about here? Planing? No. The soloist does not perform planing over the chords, or think about planing when soloing. The relevant thing is switching between F# minor and major.